# Is the denumerability of private keys a threat?

Tags: security

Since the set of all private keys is denumerable, it is at least possible to create a searcheable record of all keypairs. Which, when finished, is a killer for the whole idea. Am I right or do I miss some essential part?

Comment: You're meaning something like [this](http://directory.io/)?

Comment: @aland Clever! I think I just found the smallest vanity address: 19's compressed address starts with [`1Amy`](https://blockchain.info/address/1AmybvuPDrDpsqsgSzqbwALGcW1t6Yn9uN)

Comment: It's pretty hard to represent non-denumerable sets on a finite state digital computer.

Comment: OP - It's not denumerable, it's finite. "Denumerable" in standard mathematical terminology means countably infinite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's around 2^256 possible private keys. However, there's only 2^160 valid wallet addresses. To store each key-address pair we need 160+256 bits = 25 bytes, so the searchable record will take [several million mass of solar system if stored on 4TiB harddrives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%5E160+*+25+bytes)+%2F+(4+TiB)+*+(0.6+kg)).

But first we need to create this database. If we equip each PC on Earth (around 2 billion) with 4 GPUs (each generating around [20Mkey/s](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Vanitygen_keysearch_rate)), we will need [much more time than the age of the universe](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E160+%2F+%28%2820e6+1%2Fs%29+*+%284*2e9%29%29). By the way, we most likely will also hit the hard drive write performance limit if we write each pair to disk.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not a threat, because the number of possible private keys is about 2^256. Even if every atom on earth was a Petabyte hard drive, you would still not have nearly enough storage for a record of all keys.

(More interesting is the finite number of Bitcoin addresses, but that is still enormously large.)